# bash script remote ssh ping on unit (cisco) results with half response

Tags: linux, networking, bash, router, ssh

can someone help please?
I'm trying to catch/pipe ping response from remote cisco router over ssh (see script). Everything works well but only at ping the pipe brokes at first "!" ping response from router destination:

```
routername#ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx
Type escape sequence to abort.Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
!
```

And that's all... It seems to break after the first "!".

Where this works well and catch and give back whole ping result:

```
ssh "user@$1" 'ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx' > log
ssh user@$1 "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx" | tee -a log
```

but only as single line command.
What can I do to catch the whole output until end?

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
var1=$(ssh user@$1 << "ENDSSH"
sh version | incl System image file
sh ip interface INTx  | incl MTU
show controllers VDx | incl Speed
sh cellular 0 radio | include RSS
sh cellular 0 netw | include Selected
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx
ENDSSH)
echo "$var1" > log
```

Comment: Is this the actual code you run? or did you "simplify" it somehow? How do you examine the log file afterwards? Does `ssh "user@$1" 'ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx' > log` work better? Please respond by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski :  hey kamil.. thank you for response... yours wont work anyway... how i allready mentioned -> other commands work, except ping... which broke the log pipe after the first exclamation mark "!" which is cisco ping response character ->
`code`
var1=$(ssh user@$1 << "ENDSSH" sh version | incl System image file sh ip interface INT1 | incl MTU show controllers VDSL | incl Speed sh cellular 0 radio | include RSSI sh cellular 0 netwo | include Selected ENDSSH ) echo "$var1" > log
`code`
<-
this works fine and i get all data i need... only ping make sick... ;-)

Comment: Please confirm you invoked my command without changing its syntax, i.e. without a here document and without any intermediate variable.

Comment: hey kamil... thank you for reminding... indeed it does working fine... only when i insert it on CLI as one line... how can i pack that in batch with other commands ->> while those !!!! cisco ping feedbacks bash thinks are !! (command history)

Comment: Why do you think `!!` triggers history expansion? Are you sure or just guessing? I think your original snippet should not allow this, I really doubt any *output* can trigger it. History expansion is disabled for non-interactive shells by default. To simplify your problem: why do you need the variable in the first place? Isn't redirecting output to `log` enough? And to test one strange possibility: what is the output of `ssh "user@$1" 'ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx' | xxd | grep '!'`?

Comment: what means | xxd | ?

Comment: It means "pipe the output to `xxd` and then pipe it further".

Comment: ok that | one i know but why xxd ? or just randomly xxd like bba? that was my thought...

Comment: Because it's [the command we need](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd). Any tool with similar functionality will do. I hope it will show us if there is something strange after the first `!` in the output you get from the remote `ping`.

Comment: hey Kamil... Thx for answer... nope... nothing strange... <!!!!! Suc> appear... As five ping accomplished...

Comment: You never answered this question I asked: why do you need the variable in the first place?  Since redirection to a file seems to work, test `ssh "user@$1" > log << …` and then `var1=$(cat log)`. Is the file content OK? Is the variable content OK?

Comment: hey kamil... thought that this will be propper way adding the output to variable and pipe the echo of the variable in log file... while i couldn't handle the way putting multiple commands in one ssh "user@$1" > log
how should be the syntax in that case? therefore i did that with <<ENDSSH // ENDSSH...


many thanks in forward...

Comment: `…` in my previous comment symbolizes the rest of the here document syntax you already have in your script.

Comment: hey kamil... just adapted the script as you sugest:   
  
    `#!/bin/bash  
    echo "$1" ssh user@$1 > log << 'ENDSSH'   
    sh version | incl System image file   
    sh ip interface INTx | incl MTU  
    show controllers VDx | incl Speed  
    sh cellular 0 radio | include RSS  
    sh cellular 0 netw | include Selected  
    ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx ENDSSH`  

and i get pretty the same break with only one !  
.  
.  
.  
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
!

Comment: What if `ping` is not the last command? Add any command after `ping`. Is the output still truncated? Is the output from the extra command captured or not? If not, can you tell if the extra command even run? Maybe choose the extra command wisely so you can tell for sure.

Comment: same issue -> it breaks out of the session and don't complete other commands after ping command...regardless if ping on first place, middle or end...

Comment: I don't know Cisco *at all* but maybe there is some timeout mechanism misconfigured to kill sessions after 1 second of looking "idle" or so. This would make sense if other commands respond almost immediately. In such case `ping` is different, it deliberately waits, it doesn't produce output while it waits. I don't know why `ping` as the *only* command seems to work, so maybe I'm all wrong now. Anyway if I were you I would investigate this. Tell `ping` to use `interval 0`, it should finish faster. Then you will be able to tell if time is a factor. Can you log in interactively and not be kicked?

Comment: but when i use bash script to ping on cisco in single line as that (as you told me - thank you for that):
'ssh "user@$1" 'ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx' > log' or that 
'ssh user@$1 "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx source loopback xx" | tee -a log'
it finishes well, without braking at first !, it only appears when ping is in heredoc...
everything else is really ok... also i can login interactively... except ping i have all my needs covered...

Comment: OK. Tell me `interval 0` doesn't help and I will drop the idea.

Comment: good idea and just tryed: but cisco don't have interval, i can set only timeout which tell ping command how log to wait for response... i set to 0 where mismatch ping is guaranteed and in that case i get . as feedback which means no response... but the main is... the log also brokes after that first . (point) that could mean i'm not right regarding the ! as connection break/bash history etc... curious... ( ._.)>

Comment: How about `count 1`? Does your `ping` support this? Try.

Comment: yes... that's supported but with same result as my comment before... do I have the option to make the script or heredoc more sticky... Like wait 5sec... Sleep 5sec or time out 15sec? thank you in advance...